# window.showModalDialog and postback button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, postback, showmodaldialog

I have two pages A.aspx and B.aspx

Page A.aspx opens B.aspx as modal popup by javascript function window.showModalDialog("B.aspx");

Page B.aspx has two text boxes (Login, Password), `<asp:Button>` control and button click event in server code.

Problem is when I click on the submit button it opens me B.aspx page in new third window

How is it possible to not open new window on submit button.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply in the modal window put this to the `<HEAD>`

`<BASE target="_self">`

Answer (score 0):

move B.aspx code to B.ascx (user control)